# Open PDF in Android

Tags: android, pdf

I would like to open a PDF file from my android application. I've searched how to do it in internet, and it seems very easy, but it doesn't work, at least in my mobile (Sony XPeria P).

```
File file = ....

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                  Uri.fromFile (file));             
intent.setType("application/pdf");                  
startActivity(intent);
```

When this code is executed, a window is opened asking to choose an application to show the PDF. When I choose the Adobe Reader, it's opened by no document is shown.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: getting no errors or warnings?

Comment: Is the file valid? Can you open it directly from Adobe Reader?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am not getting any error. And the file is valid, I can open it directly from Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Its working for me

//Method to open the pdf file in the PDF Viewer

```
public void OpenPDFFile() {
    File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"PdfFile.pdf");//File path
    if (pdfFile.exists()) //Checking for the file is exist or not
    {
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
        Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        objIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        objIntent.setFlags(Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(objIntent);//Staring the pdf viewer
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java method name usually start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

The setType("application/pdf") function removes all the previous data.

Answer (score 0):

If the targetSdkVersion >= 24 we need to use file provider to get the Uri. See this post for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/8192914

So, the final code would look something like this:

```java
Uri pathUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getBaseContext(), context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", finalFile);
Intent pdfViewerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pdfViewerIntent.setDataAndType(pathUri, "application/pdf");
pdfViewerIntent.setFlags(Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
pdfViewerIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(pdfViewerIntent);
```