# Open PDF in Android with Adobe Reader

Tags: android, pdf, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open PDF in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468710/open-pdf-in-android)

I would like to open a PDF file with Adobe Reader from my android application.

I've a PDF file in /mnt/sdcard called test.pdf, and I'm using the next code:

```
file = new File ("/mnt/sdcard/test.pdf");

if (file.exists())
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");          
    startActivity(intent);              
}
```

Adobe Reader is opened when this code is executed, but the file is not opened. The file is valid.

What is the problem?

Comment: What is the value of the URI ?

Comment: The value of the URI is file:///mnt/sdcard/test.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this.

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works perfect. What I don't undestand is why it doesn't work in my way.

Comment: Maybe, there is something to do with the *setFlags*.

Comment: I remove the line 'setFlags' and works as well.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
File file=new File("/mnt/sdcard/test.pdf");
if(file.exists())
{
    Uri path=Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");

    try
    {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "No software for PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: downvoted for hardcoding "/sdcard/". No. "/mnt/sdcard/" is also wrong.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com : the value is in the question

Comment: The path is hardcoding because I'm testing how to open a PDF file.

Comment: Thanks, Naveen, it works perfect. What I don't undestand is why it doesn't work in my way.

Comment: @Eduardo this is not excuse. It's even quicker to type `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` due to autocompletion that `/mnt/sdcard`, so do your tests right.