# how to close external pdf reader activity from our app Activity?

Tags: android, pdf

how to close external pdf reader activity from our app Activity?

In my project i have one requirement like this,
i need to download &  open pdf coming from server and open it with in the app only.
i don't have any library to open pdf file ,
so i'm  using this url [Open PDF in android with Adobe Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469457/open-pdf-in-android-with-adobe-reader) code

my problem is while opening the pdf through adobe reader if  i click the home button or back button  i need to  stop opening the pdf. adobe reader is external app how  to close it through our activity?

Comment: If you dont want to open pdf in PdfViewer then Open direct url in `WebView`

Comment: no the file coming from server it self is pdf file

Comment: So you want to open in inbuilt PDF Reader?

Comment: not like that i can open it in my app also by using (intigrating) any pdf library.but i didn't find any free library that's why i'm opening pdf through inbuiltpdf reader plz help me in that way