# APV PDF Viewer crash

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am new to Android NDK.
This is my first project.
I downloaded android PDF reader from http://code.google.com/p/apv/downloads/list. 
It's compiling properly, but when I tried to load PDF from this app. It's showing below error:

```
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at cx.hell.android.pdfview.OpenFileActivity.getPDF(OpenFileActivity.java:541)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at cx.hell.android.pdfview.OpenFileActivity.startPDF(OpenFileActivity.java:502)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at cx.hell.android.pdfview.OpenFileActivity.onCreate(OpenFileActivity.java:219)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library pdfview2 not found
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at cx.hell.android.lib.pdf.PDF.<clinit>(PDF.java:25)
07-03 10:18:06.171: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     ... 16 more
```

I saw a similar error in so many questions. 
Since I am new to NDK, I couldn't understand what to do.

Comment: is there by any chance you have other required dependencies you forgot to include? since your error is caused by ` Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library pdfview2 not found`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this caused the error 
`Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library pdfview2 not found`

Just download this   library, [pdfview2](http://code.google.com/p/apv/downloads/detail?name=pdfview2.apk)

open the  file using any zip tool and copy the necessary files in your project and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error when you don't load the native library. This will happen for a lot of reasons. First, you need to make sure your `Android.mk` file (in your `jni` directory) is set up properly. Assuming it (or they) are set up correctly, find the line that looks something like this:

```
LOCAL_MODULE := libpdfview2
```

Note the name of this, as it is important. Next, add the following lines to the top of your Activity (or Application in a multi-Activity app):

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("pdfview2");
}
```

Here, note the name. It is the name of the local module with the lib prefix removed. Assuming the NDK build works, and the Android.mk files are set up correctly, this will solve your issue.

---

**Edit**

Also, have you read the info about building the library, [here](http://code.google.com/p/apv/wiki/Building)?

Answer (score 1):

There's another solution for PDF opening, take a peek here:

[Open PDF in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468710/open-pdf-in-android)

I think that without your code it will be difficult to imagine what's happening.

Comment: hii my problem is i should not use other appliactions to launch pdf.so its not helpful to me

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library pdfview2 not found
```

The above exception is caused due to link is not found for the specified library which is self explanatory but actually reason is when the .so file of the related project has been created from the project the .so functions are created according the package structure of the project. so we can not directly use that .so in our project.

you need to re-build the .so file with your application package and after that this error will  not be valid and you will be able to get the native function access too.